# Display output while inside of raw_input()

Tags: python, sockets, client

I am implementing a chat server, and I currently have a list of client sockets I'd like to send information through, the issue is that the client exists in a raw_input() state in order to send the message to be relayed through the server, and each client's buffer is being filled up until that client itself enters something in the raw_input() field, at which point it prints its receive buffer as a single line chunk.

I would like each client to get an immediate display of what's in their buffer, even though they are stuck inside of raw_input().

Here is my output:

cli1.py

```
Your Message: test
Your Message: Received  "'test'"
test
Received  "'test'"
Your Message:
```

cli2.py

```
Your Message: test
Your Message: Received  "'test'"
1
Received  "'test''test'"
Your Message:
```

server.py

```
Server is running......
('127.0.0.1', 58919) is Connected
('127.0.0.1', 58920) is Connected
Received Message 'test'
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004b6f30>
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004e98a0>
Received Message 'test'
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004b6f30>
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004e98a0>
Received Message 'test'
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004b6f30>
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004e98a0>
Received Message '1'
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004b6f30>
we have connected:  <socket._socketobject object at 0x1004e98a0>
```

and my actual code:

cli1 = cli2:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import sys

def iamclient():
    message = raw_input("Your Message: ")
    s.send(message)
    reply = s.recv(1024) # 1024 is max data that can be received
    print "Received ", repr(reply)

HOST = ''
PORT = 8003

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # client-side, connects to a host
except:
    print 'Max capacity reached, try again later'
    s.close()
    sys.exit()


Thread(target=iamclient).start()
while True:
    iamclient()

s.close()
```

server.py

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

def clientHandler():
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connlist.append(conn)
    print addr, "is Connected"
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print "Received Message", repr(data)
        for i in connlist:
            print "we have connected: ",i
            i.send(repr(data))


HOST = '' #localhost
PORT = 8003

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2)

connlist = []

print "Server is running......"

#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()

for i in range(2):
    Thread(target=clientHandler).start()

s.close()
```

Comment: `raw_input` does a blocking call

Comment: What should I do? What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (as @thefourtheye said) `raw_input` is an I/O block on the main thread, so you need to create a separate thread to print messages.

Multithreading solution:

```
>>> def print_message():
    time.sleep(5)
    print "message"


>>> bgThread = Thread(target=print_message)
>>> bgThread.start()
>>> x = raw_input()
message
input is entered here
>>> print x
input is entered here
```

Use a separate `Thread` for receiving and printing messages.

Comment: As an additional note, I think you aren't using `Thread`s correctly. In your client code you start a Thread for `iamclient()` to run it once, but then you run it again (unthreaded) many times.