# How to print while waiting for input?

Tags: python, multithreading, printing, client

```
def receivedata(self):
    while True:
        data = self.soc.recv(1024)
        if data != "" or data != '' or data != "":
            sys.stdout.write("Recv>> ")
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if data == "Server Shutdown":
                self.soc.close()
        elif not data:
            continue
def senddata(self):
    while True:
        try:
            sys.stdout.write("Send>> ")
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            self.soc.send(msg)
        except socket.error:
            sys.stdout.write("Socket Connection Timed Out")
```

This is part of my client code of python, and what I expect from this is while this waits for user input, it prints what it receives from server.

However, client does not print anything when it is waiting for user input — it only prints when something has been entered by user.

Is there a way that I could change this so that it prints even when it is waiting for user input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display output while inside of raw\_input()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240533/display-output-while-inside-of-raw-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program needs to wait on 2 separate events (user input and incoming socket data), you'll have to use threads, something like:

```
recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receivedata)
recv_thread.setDaemon(True)
recv_thread.start()
senddata()
```

Couple of things about the code:

- when `socket.error` is encountered it can be something other than timeout.
- at one point you will need to exit the `while` loop from *senddata* (when the user input a certain text? or) in case of exception.
- also add exception handling in *receivedata*
- `if` statement in *receivedata* is not OK. you could replace it to:

  ```
  if data:
      ...if statements...
  ```